# Average distance between consecutive uniformly distributed values

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Say I have a list of values $(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ and $X_i$ is a uniform random variable between 0 and 1.

Let $(Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)$ be the ordered list of those values. How do I find the expected distance between $Y_i$ and $Y_{i+1}$?

Comment: As to intuition, $n$ points defines $n+1$ segments ... not $n$ segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeking to find $$\mathbb{E}\left(\vert Y_{i+1} - Y_{i} \vert \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( Y_{i+1} - Y_{i} \right) = \mathbb{E}\left(Y_{i+1}\right) - \mathbb{E}\left(Y_i\right) = \frac{i+1}{n+1} - \frac{i}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

The expectation of $Y_i$ is easy to find, noting that $Y_i \sim \mathrm{Beta}\left(i, n+1-i\right)$:
$$
   \mathbb{E}\left(Y_i\right) = \frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{i}{n+1}
$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Beta distribution, could you explain (or give pointers) why $Y_i$ has such a distribution? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Manux Alternatively, you could use the pdf for $Y_i$ from wiki page on [order statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) and integrate.

Comment: Adding to Manux's comment, the intuition why $Y_i$ is Beta(i,n-i+1) is simply: If $Y_i$ is close to $u$, this means $i-1$ uniforms are smaller than $u$ and $n-i$ are larger. For every such choice of variables, the probability is roughly $u^{i-1}(1-u)^{n-i}$. The factorial term comes because of the choices of variables you can put to the left or right.